# Compute Mean of off diagonal and mean diagonal elements for every 10 rows and 10 columns of matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of 100r,100c and I need to calculate the mean of off-diagonal elements row 1:10, col 1:10 (upper and lower triangle) and the mean of diagonal elements (1:10). The rest of the data continue as the same pattern of 11:20, 21:30 and so on.
I anticipate the end result would become a 10x10 matrix.

```
a <- runif(100,0.0,1.0)
b <- matrix(a, 10,10)

dput(b[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.84062766819261, 0.147046645870432, 0.400851072976366, 
0.413125045597553, 0.983001669868827, 0.875247176503763, 0.780131382867694, 
0.135052096098661, 0.697219847934321, 0.124223494203761, 0.341172023210675, 
0.0648272060789168, 0.495929004857317, 0.560068692779168, 0.427216225070879, 
0.322575035970658, 0.380825364030898, 0.268939214758575, 0.308511241106316, 
0.583480153232813, 0.220581432571635, 0.440520159434527, 0.281114168930799, 
0.192230961984023, 0.468790194252506), dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

I've tried the below code, but it did not produce what I need, perhaps its lack of completeness. I hope there will be some simplistic approach to this.

```
group_number <-rep(1:(nrow(d_num)/10),each=10)
Mean_vals <- aggregate(d_num, by=list(group_number), mean)
```

Any suggestions please, thank you for your great help

Comment: So one of the sub-matrices in question is the non-diag elements in M[1:10, 11:20]?

Comment: @IRTFM, yes, the final matrix is a combination of non-diagonals and diagonals averages for each 10 segments (1:10, 11:20. 21:30, 31:40,....)

Comment: But you said the results would fit into a 10x10 structure and if we only work with the 10 matrices off the main diagonal we only get 10

Comment: It's unclear how the output matrix is a combination of averages. For the output matrix, what would be the first element with the following input matrix?

`set.seed(1); b <- matrix(runif(100), 10)`